# Zuul and Eureka setup acting strange

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I have setup a zuul proxy with eureka(not as a separate service).
Sometimes when i try to proxy to my service I get the following error:

```
12-04-2019 13:03:05.667 [http-nio-8761-exec-8] WARN  o.s.c.n.z.f.post.SendErrorFilter.run - Error during filtering
com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.handleException(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:198)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:173)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.run(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:119)
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:117)
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:193)
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:157)
    at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.route(FilterProcessor.java:118)
    at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.route(ZuulRunner.java:96)
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.route(ZuulServlet.java:116)
    at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:165)
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController.handleRequest(ZuulController.java:45)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038)
    ...........................
```

After that it says:

```
Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: EXAMPLE-SERVICE
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerContext.getServerFromLoadBalancer(LoadBalancerContext.java:483)
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:184)
    at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:180)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:94)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeConcatMap.call(OnSubscribeConcatMap.java:42)
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10327)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber$1.call(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:127)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.enqueue(TrampolineScheduler.java:73)
    at rx.internal.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.schedule(TrampolineScheduler.java:52)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber.onNext(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:79)
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber.onNext(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:45)
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$WeakSingleProducer.request(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:276)
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:209)
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:138)
    at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$JustOnSubscribe.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:129)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:48)
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)

    .........................
```

I try a couple more requests on the same endpoint and it prints this:

```
12-04-2019 13:03:20.417 [PollingServerListUpdater-0] INFO  c.n.config.ChainedDynamicProperty.checkAndFlip - Flipping property: EXAMPLE-SERVICE.ribbon.ActiveConnectionsLimit to use NEXT property: niws.loadbalancer.availabilityFilteringRule.activeConnectionsLimit = 2147483647
```

And suddenly everything works....??!??

Here is some info about both services:

**Eureka/Proxy Service:**

```
//application.properties
server.port=8761
spring.application.name=proxyservice
#This is a eureka server so no need to register
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
#This is a eureka server no need to fetch registry
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
#Register url for client
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka

#Zuul proxying
#All url come with prefix/api will interpret
zuul.prefix=/api
ribbon.ReadTimeout=60000
#Routes
zuul.routes.student-service.path=/example/**
zuul.routes.student-service.serviceId=EXAMPLE-SERVICE

//pom.xml
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

//Application.java

```
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableEurekaServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

**EXAMPLE-SERVICE:**

```
//application.properties
server.port=8098
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
eureka.client.healthcheck.enabled=true
spring.application.name=sirma-service
```

Comment: I wouldn't run eureka server and zuul in the same application. Eureka server is meant to be stand alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to use Eureka Discovery Client because you have mentioned `eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone` for Eureka Client and you are using in Application `@EnableEurekaServer`.

You need to use `@EnableDiscoveryClient`, So that Your Application will be registered with Eureka Naming Server.